Imports and namespaces in leetcode project

I have an isssue with using imports in my project. Looking for configuration that will allow me to use imports and namespaces to avoid getting error for duplicated variable names, etc.

I have created a local project for resolving some tasks from leetcode.
Its structure is like this
-Leetcode
-Tasks
-common
-TreeNode.ts
-226
-226.ts
-import
-226_import.ts
Here 226.ts looks like this:
/* eslint-disable no-inner-declarations */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-namespace */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
namespace _226 {    
    // Definition for a binary tree node.
    class TreeNode {
        val: number
        left: TreeNode | null
        right: TreeNode | null
        constructor(val?: number, left?: TreeNode | null, right?: TreeNode | null) {
            this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
            this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
            this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
        }
    }    

    function invertTree(root: TreeNode | null): TreeNode | null {
        if (root === null) return null;
        const temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;
        invertTree(root.left);
        invertTree(root.right);
        return root;        
    }
    // ...
    namespace _2 {
        const root: TreeNode = 
        new TreeNode(2, 
            new TreeNode(1), 
            new TreeNode(3));
        invertTree(root);
        console.log(root);  // Output: 2,3,1

    }
    // ...
}

In 226_import.ts I have the same code without - Definition for a binary tree node - but with import before namespaces import TreeNode from "../common/TreeNode.ts"; and ofc class TreeNode in that file.
I run files like that:
px ts-node .\tasks\import\226_import.ts
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for E:\_Programming\leetcode\tasks\import\226_import.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:176:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:219:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:133:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:570:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:445:45)
    at async ModuleJob._link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:106:19) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

Works for files where I put class definition inside namespace, but if I add import instead there is such error as above.
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "leetcode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.57",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  }
}


This is my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2020",
      "lib": [
          "ES5",
          "ES6",
          "ES2019",
          "DOM"
      ],
      "module": "ES2020",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "types": [],
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strict": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
      "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
      "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["tasks/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.md"]
}


Question: Can I amend my configuration that so imports will work?
Adding type modele (as it is added in package.json) or different versions of module or target does not resolve problem.
